# Bosch dishwasher not starting

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch SMV53M integrated dishwasher that has stopped running.  When I press start I here drain start for a couple of seconds like normal but then tap symbol and sunshine symbols flash up and nothing happens.  I have cleaned filter at tap end and filled up rinse aid but still the same.  A y ideas please?

Comment: Sounds like your heating element is kaput. Have you tried running it with no heat?

Comment: And do you get a numeric code? http://removeandreplace.com/2015/10/09/bosch-dishwasher-error-codes-how-to-clear-what-to-check/

Comment: It doesn't give me option to run with no heat as far as I can see.  I don't get a numeric code just the symbols

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual you did almost everything right. The one thing you didn't do or mention, was unplugging or killing the power to the washer. This needs to be done in order for the faults to clear or reset. Unplug or kill the power for a minute & everything should work beautifully again...so implies the manual.

Comment: I have had it unplugged all night and still the same.

Comment: Well then, you did absolutely everything right. Unless you didn't turn the water back on after re-connecting the supply line. You'll need to call Bosch & find out what other options there are. I wish I could be more useful. But, these weren't actual Error Codes for anything being broken & you did everything that the manual says to do.